# What is wrong with promise resolving?

Tags: arrays, node.js

Any ideas? Why does node say 'filename is undefined'? Thanks.
Contract, policy ans invoice functions resolve with no data, just resolve().

```
var dc = function(data) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    var filename = 'Test';

    var contract = function() { ... }

    var policy = function() { ... }

    var invoice = function() { ... }

    contract().then(invoice().then(policy().then(function() {
        console.log(filename); // Test
        resolve(filename); // UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): ReferenceError: filename is not defined
    })))
})

}
```

Comment: Each of there functions return a promise. I need to resolve the common promise after all internal promises are resolved.

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284107/what-is-wrong-with-promise-resolving/41284674#41284674) below answer your question? If so then you may consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so that other people who search for this topic could see that it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot write:

```
contract().then(invoice() ... )
```

(that would work if the `invoice()` function returned *another* function to act as a `then` handler)

You have to write:

```
contract().then(function (value) { invoice() ... })
```

Or:

```
contract().then(value => invoice() ... )
```

Or maybe this if one function should handle the result of other function:

```
contract().then(invoice).then(policy).then(function (result) { ... });
```

What you have to pass as an argument to `then` is a function, not a result of calling a function (which is probably a promise in your example).

I don't know if that's the only problem with your approach but it is  certainly one of the problems. Of course it may work but probably not how you expect.

### 2017 Update

If you use ES2017 async/await that's available in Node since v7.0 then instead of:

```
contract().then(invoice).then(policy).then((result) => { ... });
```

you can use:

```
let a = await contract();
let b = await invoice(a);
let c = await policy(b);
// here your `result` is in `c`
```

or even this:

```
let result = await policy(await invoice(await contract()));
```

Note that you can only use it in functions declared with the `async` keyword. This works on Node since version 7. For older versions of Node you can use a similar thing with a slightly different syntax using generator-based coroutines, or you can use Babel to transpile your code if that's what you prefer of if that what you already do.

This is quite a new feature but there are a lot of questions on Stack Overflow about it. See:

- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [Do async in a blocking program language way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43973850/do-async-in-a-blocking-program-language-way/43976255#43976255)
- [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await/40886720#40886720)
- [Use await outside async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701963/use-await-outside-async/42702019#42702019)
- [Using acyns/await in Node 6 with Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299393/using-acyns-await-in-node-6-with-babel/42299652#42299652)
- [When do async methods throw and how do you catch them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203070/when-do-async-methods-throw-and-how-do-you-catch-them/42203405#42203405)
- [using promises in node.js to create and compare two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160253/using-promises-in-node-js-to-create-and-compare-two-arrays/42160417#42160417)
- [Keeping Promise Chains Readable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765589/keeping-promise-chains-readable/42765827#42765827)
- [function will return null from javascript post/get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071337/function-will-return-null-from-javascript-post-get/42072290#42072290)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't care about the order, in which case you could use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Does this work for you? It will resolve once all of the promises have been resolved, or it will reject as soon as any one of them rejects.

```
function contract(data) { return new Promise(...) }
function policy(data) { return new Promise(...) }
function invoice(data) { return new Promise(...) }

function dc(data) {
  var filename = 'Test';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    Promise.all([contract(data), policy(data), invoice(data)]).then(
      function (values) {
        console.log(filename);
        resolve(filename)
      },
      function (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

If you care about the order, then you do have to chain them, like you've tried to do. You're code is passing *promises* as an argument to `then`. You need to pass *functions*.

```
function contract(data) { return new Promise(...) }
function policy(data) { return new Promise(...) }
function invoice(data) { return new Promise(...) }

function dc(data) {
  var filename = 'Test';
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    contract(data).then(
      function (contract_res) {
        policy(data).then(
          function (policy_res) {
            invoice(data).then(
              function (invoice_res) {
                console.log(filename);
                resolve(filename);
              },
              function (err) { reject(err); } // invoice promise rejected
            );
          },
          function (err) { reject(err); } // policy promise rejected
        );
      },
      function (err) { reject(err); } // contract policy rejected
    );
  });
}
```

You may be able to simplify this with `catch`, but the deep nesting is a pain. Take a look at this post about [flattening Promise chains](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/).