# yarn build (serve -s build) causing unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, yarnpkg

serve -s build is causing the following error. Why is it an unexpected identifier when it's an argument? Thank you for your help

```
const updateCheck = async isDebugging => (
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

My system is

```
  System Version: macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 17.5.0
  Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
  Secure Virtual Memory: Enabled
  System Integrity Protection: Enabled
  Time since boot: 5 days 8:33
```

and I am using 
node --version v6.10.3
yarn --version 0.27.5

Comment: does such an old version of node understand `async` without some sort of command line option, perhaps?

Comment: async/await didn't appear in node until 7.5 - so, I think you'll need some sort of transpilier ... or a current version of node - any reason you don't at least use node 8.x?

Comment: This answer might help with setting up babel with node v6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299393/using-async-await-in-node-6-with-babel/42300449

Answer (score 0):

Updating your node version to the LTS edition will resolve your issue.