# Upload webscraped data with puppeteer to firebase cloud storage in node.js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions

I’m trying to webscrape a press site, open every link of the articles and get the data. I was able to webscrape with puppeteer but cannot upload it to fire base cloud storage. How do I do that every hour or so?
I webscraped in asynchrones function and then called it in the cloud function:
I used puppeteer to scrape the links of the articles from newsroom website and then used the links to get more information from the articles. I first had everything in a single async function but cloud functions threw an error that there should not be any awaits in a loop.

**UPDATE:**

I implanted the code above in a firebase function but still get no-await in loop error.

Comment: I think it would be easier, if you shared your first version where you had everything in one function. Note: There are many unused imports (title, link, resolve, reject) at the start of your script. You might want to delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of things wrong here, but you are on a good path of getting this to work. The main problem is, that you can't have `await` within a `try {} catch {}` block. Asynchronous JavaScript has a different way of dealing with errors. See: [try/catch blocks with async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await).

In your case, it's totally fine to write everything in one async function. Here is how I would do it:

```
async function scrapeIfc() {
  const completeData = [];
  const url = 'https://www.ifc.org/wps/wcm/connect/news_ext_content/ifc_external_corporate_site/news+and+events/pressroom/press+releases';

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

  const links = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('h3 > a')).map(anchor => anchor.href)
  );

  for (const link of links) {
    const newPage = await browser.newPage();
    await newPage.goto(link);

    const data = await newPage.evaluate(() => {
      const titleElement = document.querySelector('td[class="PressTitle"] > h3');
      const contactElement = document.querySelector('center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td');
      const txtElement = document.querySelector('center > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td');

      return {
        source: 'ITC',
        title: titleElement ? titleElement.innerText : undefined,
        contact: contactElement ? contactElement.innerText : undefined,
        txt: txtElement ? txtElement.innerText : undefined,
      }
    })

    completeData.push(data);
    newPage.close();
  }

  await browser.close();

  return completeData;
}
```

There is couple of other things you should note:

- You have a bunch of unused import `title`, `link`, `resolve` and `reject` the head of your script, which might have been added automatically by your code editor. Get rid of them, as they might overwrite the real variables.
- I changed your `document.querySelector`s to be more specific, as I couldn't select the actual elements from the ITC website. You might need to revise them.
- For local development I use Google's [functions-framework](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/functions-framework?hl=de), which helps me to run and test the function locally before deploying. If you have errors on your local machine, you'll have error when deploying to Google Cloud.
- (Opinion) If you don't need Firebase, I would run this with Google Cloud Functions, Cloud Scheduler and the Cloud Firestore. For me, this has been the go-to workflow for periodic web scraping.
- (Opinion) Puppeteer might be overkill for scraping a simple static website, since it runs in a headless Browser. Something like Cheerio is much more lightweight and much faster.

Hope I could help. If you encounter other problems, let us know. Welcome to the Stack Overflow community!