# How to check if browser supports `navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' })`?

Tags: javascript

How to check if browser supports `navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' })` ?

Firefox has error when using the above code:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: 'microphone' (value of 'name' member of PermissionDescriptor) is not a valid value for enumeration PermissionName.

But surprizingly when you log this code in firefox you get "function" !!!:

```
typeof navigator.permissions.query
```

How to check if browser supports `navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' })` ?

Comment: I suppose you could just try-catch the call...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a promise, you can try using `catch`.

i.e.:

```
navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' }).catch(e => console.log("i'm catching the error"))
```

You can also await and use `try/catch` approach.

[This question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884153/try-catch-blocks-with-async-await)